# A default style for all SE sites and the ability to disable custom styles for particular SE site?

Tags: feature-request, design

Different SE sites have different styles. How about an (optional) default style for all of them?

Like reddit has custom styles for different subreddits but there's still an option to disable them.

Comment: I'm not sure this is feasible. AFAIK, the different site styles aren't just “skins” on the same underlying HTML, but actually involve custom HTML as well. Forcing the sites to serve up different HTML for different users would probably double(?) the storage used by the cache servers.

Answer (score 1):

This already exists, it just isn't optional.

Beta sites are all given the same theme when they're launched, and they keep that theme up until the Stack Exchange team 'graduates' the site. At that point, the site gets its own design.

I'm not sure we need to make that optional - most people tend to agree that the custom themes look better than the default beta theme, so there's not much point using up extra server resources to serve out different versions of a site to different people.